# Can I declare Brood Sliver's tokens as attackers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So in my Sliver deck I am running [Brood Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brood%20Sliver) and [Heart Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Heart%20Sliver). Let's say they're both on the battlefield, and a sliver deals damage to a player. Could I declare the tokens made as attackers or is it too late?

Sorry if this question probably has an obvious answer, it's just something I was wondering about.

Comment: If you [somehow](http://magiccards.info/gtc/en/143.html) managed to create an additional combat phase, they would be able to attack in that one.

Comment: You might want to check out Aggravated Assault. I have a Sliver Commander deck, and I find it quite fun. Especially with Manaweft Sliver and 5 other Slivers.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't attack with those Sliver tokens the same turn you get them. In your combat phase, the following steps happen:

1. You declare what creatures are attacking.
2. Your opponents declare what creatures are blocking.
3. Combat damage is dealt.

Brood Sliver's ability triggers when a Sliver deals combat damage, so it is only in the Combat Damage Step that you get the tokens. At this point you have already finished dealing damage, so there's no chance to attack with the new tokens.